# Изменение объектов Page через Window, в котором отображается Page (C#, WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, listview

**Всем привет, при создании учебного проекта на WPF появился вопрос как можно корректно изменять данные Page вне самого Page?** В моём случае это обновление listview из page, которое я реализовал методом, принадлежащим window, в котором отображается данный Page (потому что у меня есть leftbar внутри Window, по которому задаются параметры фильтрации для listview)

[image]

listview из page сохраняется в отдельном классе, чтобы получить к нему доступ вне Page

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

сохранение listview из page в публичное статичное поле listView, чтобы получать доступ к нему вне страницы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам метод обновления listview (не имеет существенного значения, вставил для большей понятности)

**Буду очень благодарен за помощь!**

Comment: Пожалуйста вставьте код текстом

Comment: Только код со скринов?

Comment: Это ваш вопрос, вам решать, но код скринами здесь прикладывать не стоит.